# How can I print multiple files on choose file input? Uri Intent with multiple files on OnActivityResult

Tags: android

Main Activity create WebView:

```
WebView webView;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String mCM;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
private final static int FCR=1;
```

Activity Result called by onShowFileChooser event:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String s = "";
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                if(null == mUMA){
                    return;
                }
                    if(clipData == null){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "no clip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Uri uri = intent.getData();
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(uri.toString())};
                        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                        return;
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "clip", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here I tried to return all files selected by the user to put them into the input multiple file on js code, but this doesn't work because it crashes.

The 's' string is not valid for me because it is a string of all uri but the function onReceiveValue accepts just one string uri so it doesn't work.

What about an array of uri.toString()?

```
                        for(int i=0; i<clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            s+=uri.toString()+"\n";
                        }
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(s)};
                        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                        return;
                    }
```

this is the end of the for cycle to put down the files choose by the user but it crashes in this point: results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(s)};

```
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    }else{
        if(requestCode == FCR){
            if(null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : 
    intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }

    return;
}

@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
```

onCreate function:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    assert webView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("token=" + token, "UTF-8");
    webView.postUrl("https://www.example.com/area_utenti.php", post);
```

Web Chrome Client

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

    onShowFileChooser and StartActivityForResult:
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
            if(mUMA != null){
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                File photoFile = null;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "takePic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if(photoFile != null){
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mCM, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                }else{
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, true);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if(takePictureIntent != null){
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            }else{
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "buono", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of code considering your title makes it sound like you are just looking for a tutorial type of thing. Is any of the code relevant to your specific question?

Comment: I changed it better